How to change environment variable values at runtime in NEXT.JS without having to rebuild the project again
I have a NEXT.JS  project and I want to deploy it to 3 different environments. For example: SIT, UAT, PROD, all these 3 environments have different configuration values like API_URL and API_KEY which must be changed accordingly. So I have to build the project again and again every time I want to deploy to another environment because by default NEXT.JS read those values at build time which can't be changed once the project is already built. In this project I use Pages router.
I want to build it just one time and deploy it to anywhere by just changing the environment values in .env file following the The Twelve-Factor-App methodology. For instance, I can do that with my spring boot project where I just build it one time and then when I want to deploy to other environments I just need to change the environment values in .env file and restart the app but with NEXT.JS, it seems to be tricky.

Could you share us a hello world with next to try?

Env variable = Backend
Since you are talking about env variables (which is ultra good), react should discarded for simplicty. I mean the the changing variable should be used at the backed layer (nodejs). In your example, the API_URL and API_KEY should be used not at the react level, instead of that, at the backend layer. Something like:

So the next.js backend should use the env variables to do whatever is needed and then return the data to the react layer using the same endpoint. So if you deploy to another server, just change the env variables at backend and assign another domain.
AJAX

Remember that at the frontend layer (react) for security you should not use static variables because as you mentioned, they will be inside of the js build. Only short live tokens (oauth2) should ve used at the frontend layer

Anyway, if you are forced to use the API_URL and API_KEY at the frontend layer (react), you can use these approach:

Create one endpoint in the next.js backend called /spa-settings
This endpoint have access to the os in the backend so is able to read any env variable
Return the required env variables as a json response of /spa-settings

{
  "API_URL":"www.foo-api.com/productos",
  "API_KEY":"e3c06b64-f242-4ca7"
}


If you will have several en variables to be exposed you could use the approach of CRA in which all the prefixed variables with REACT_APP_ are exposed.
Read these value at the entrypoint of react application and expose the values to all the react files (javascript) using any strategy like localstorage, state , global variables, etc

import axios from "axios";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

axios.get("./settings.json").then(response => response.data)
.then((data) => {
  console.log("settings:", JSON.stringify(data))
  localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(data));
  const container = document.getElementById('root');
  const root = createRoot(container); 
  root.render(<App />);
});


Then on any react file you will be able to access the variables

1 build, N deploys
With these approaches you will need to  build your application just one time and the deploy anywhere just setting the required env variables before the startup
References

I used the explained strategy to build this lightweight server for any spa (react, angular, vue, etc)

https://github.com/usil/nodeboot-spa-server


Several build problem in spas
https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/just-one-build-for-spas
https://jrichardsz.github.io/web/how-serve-spa-csr-react-angular-vue-webs
Get React to talk to backend API server on a different EC2 instance in production
Is it possible to use a React server enviroment variables into frontend at client side?
How to use node package dotenv to access local development environment variables in Red Hat OpenShift application?
How to use variable substitution in Frontend js applications like backend applications?
How to manage credentials with a multi-stages, single-environment Rails app?
How to detect environment method is running in JS util file (CRA)
how do i use environment variables in my react project?
Unable to access API key in Heroku Config Vars from Javascript app
How to deploy NextJS App with CI/CD [jenkins] [docker] [nginx]

